# NullReferenceException in comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, LivePacketDevice> copyOfAdapters = find_adapter.Adapters;
    copyOfAdapters.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedText);
    Dictionary<string, LivePacketDevice> copyOfAdapters22 = copyOfAdapters;

}
```

After start project the exeption is throwed

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ...... but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at the end of first line of method. But `find_adapter` was created in constructor of the Form. So where is mistake?
I really do not know :/
THX

Comment: What does your IDE tell you is the null item if you set a breakpoint?

Comment: find_adapter is null .... but why is throwed this issue immediately after run programm and no after click on combobox?

Comment: You clearly haven't set find_adapter to anything (other than null) before calling this code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should to add check on null  value and try to use `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` instead `comboBox1.SelectedText`

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (find_adapter.Adapters == null || !find_adapter.Adapters.Any())
        {
          Dictionary<string, LivePacketDevice> copyOfAdapters = find_adapter.Adapters;
          copyOfAdapters.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
          var copyOfAdapters22 = new Dictionary<string, LivePacketDevice>(copyOfAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: I cant create another question for 90 min. Can I ask you hear? ... It is about this method and deleting from dictionary.